# Laravel Weekly Schedule / Timetable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

For my Laravel App I need a Weekly Schedule, that is the same for every week. So a Monday 'till Sunday.

It's a schedule like this e.g.:

- MO: 10:00 - 11:00 > cleaning
- MO: 12:00 - 12:30 > lunch
- MO: 17:00 - 17:45 > something else

I was thinking of the following Model:

```
#schedule
day_of_the_week: integer
time_start_hours: integer
time_start_minutes: integer 
time_stop_hours: integer
time_stop_minutes: integer 
task: text
```

But I think I'm thinking to difficult. There should be an easier way then this. Right?
It should have been easier when it was based on dates. But the schedule is the same for each week.

Also because I wan't to do the following:

- List items for each day, ordered by time
- Highlight current task (based on current day/time)
- Highlight new task separate (like a widget, what task is next on schedule)

Are there any advantages I can use in L4? With Eloquent, Carbon etc.

I found some things in the schema like: `$table->time('from');`, instead of adding a hours and minutes field in the model.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you trying to have some kind of job executed at those times, like a cron job?

Comment: nothing with cronjobs. i'm looking for an easy way to take advantage of the $table->time() instead of $table->datetime()'s. combined with days of the week. i'm especially stuck on how to check what's  the next or current lesson in time, when you use time(). it's easy when you use datetimes in combination with Carbon.

Comment: So you need to be able to fetch all tasks for the current day from the database and then be able to tell if a task is a current task or if it is the next task?

Comment: use case: you login at 17:35. current task is: eating (show this). next task is at 19:00 (show this). Task after that is tomorrow at 10:00 (show this).

Answer (score -1):

So you need to fetch a list of the current task and the 2 tasks after that one ordered in the correct way.

```
Model::where('task_time', '>', $currentTime)->take(3)->orderBy('task_time', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: No, that's not it. Tried that before. But then you still can't figure out if a task is for Mondays, when you check the page Sundays.

Comment: Well why don't you do two queries.  One for the current tasks and one for the tasks tomorrow.  Then you would have those in two different variables so you would know which one is which.